# how to add multiple names spaces and Classes within those for one solution

Tags: c#

As a first simple exercise, I ask you to create a new C# Console App in Visual Studio.

- This app must have 2 different namespaces, and each namespace contain at least one class with a method to display the word "Hello, this is XXX class" in console, where XXX is the parent class. You can code it on the same file or create different files for different namespaces.
- In the Main method of the default class called Program, you must be able to show all the different "Hello..." messages in console, being able to call different classes and methods you just have created.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace First
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello this is The FIRST Class.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

namespace Second
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main1(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, this is the SECOND Class.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

I was hoping both Name spaces would show the individual classes. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here

Comment: You don't get two Main Methods. The assignment wants *one* main method that uses two different classes (that are in different namespaces)

Comment: What is your Program code? you should be creating two classes and should be calling these classes inside Main .

Answer (score 3):

You should be creating two classes and should call respective methods from Main method.

```
using First;
using Second;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication16
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            FirstClass fc = new FirstClass();
            fc.DisplayHello();
            SecondClass sc = new SecondClass();
            sc.DisplayHello();
        }
    }
}

namespace First
{
    internal class FirstClass
    {
        public void DisplayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello this is The FIRST Class.");
        }
    }
}

namespace Second
{
    internal class SecondClass
    {
        public void DisplayHello()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello this is The SECOND Class.");
        }
    }
}
```